# How to distinguish between transparent (water-like) and opaque (milk-like) skin lotions?

Tags: vocabulary

In cosmetics there are 2 distinct kinds of skin lotions and some languages (but not English, as far as I know) include distinct words to name them: 1. transparent, water-like looking lotions usually containing solvents and antiseptics and meant for skin cleansing ("pleťová voda" (literally "skin water") in Czech, "лосьон" (literally "lotion") in Russian) 2. opaque (non-transparent), milky/creamy lotions, usually containing fatty compounds and meant for skin treatment and moisturizing ("pleťové mléko" (literally "skin milk") in Czech, "молочко для лица/тела" (literally "face/body milk") in Russian).

What would be the shortest while informative distinct names (not necessarily of a single word) for these?

UPDATE: I am considering using "clear lotion" for the first kind and "creamy lotion" for the second kind but am not sure yet.

Comment: If it's a cleanser, it's not a lotion at all. "Lotion" describes the purpose, not the appearance.

Comment: What about https://www.google.com/search?q=cleansing+lotion @Marthaª? Incorrect word usage?

Comment: I guess that's an exception; there's a reason I posted a comment, not an answer. :)

Comment: @Marthaª Far be it from me to claim expertise in such a field, but my dictionary defines *lotion* as *a thick smooth liquid preparation designed to be applied to the shin for medicinal or cosmetic purposes*.

Comment: In the health and beauty industry in the US, there are many terms used for topically applied products, depending on the properties and benefits - including: lotion, ointment, wash, cleanser, gel, moisturizer, foundation, cream, milk, soap, body wash, shampoo, conditioner, balm, and more I probably don't know of.  What links those words is the relative viscosity of the product - some runny, some quite thick.  You'd probably be better off using something more descriptive than 'clear lotion' and 'milky lotion' if you want the product to be understood, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

`Water lotion` and `milk lotion`/`skin milk` are common names for those, though I am not sure if there are specific terms that are used as definitions.

Comment: I've never heard "water lotion", and both "milk lotion" and "skin milk" would lead me to expect either a product containing actual milk, or a very thin, runny lotion (or both).

Answer (score 1):

transparent & skin-tone

Note that 'skin-tone' applications can also be "transparent," which is, actually, translucent.

Comment: Skin-tone? When did makeup enter this question?